# jQuery CSS method update on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vertical-alignment, viewport, window-resize

After struggling to vertically centre a `div` inside the `body` element using the "conventional" methods, I've decided to create a small jQuery function that figures out how far from the top an element needs to be to be "centred".

It works like this:

1. Get container height,
2. Get child height,
3. *"top"* = *"(container.height - child.height) / 2"*
4. Set margin top of child to the value of *"top"*.

For example if the `body` had a width and height of `1000px` and this `body` had a `div.inner` child that had a width and height of `400px` the `margin-top` of `div.inner` would be `300px` because `(1000-400) / 2 = 300`.

Here is a diagram to further explain what I mean:

[image: Image Diagram]

**NOTE**: `X` represents the `margin-top` of the `div.inner` (as I didn't have enough space for *"Margin Top = "*).

To my amazement this actually works!!! Here is the test code:

```js
// set the margin top for ".vertical-centre" elements
$(".vertical-centre").each(function() {
  // set the margin-top for the child
  $(this).css("margin-top", function() {
    // NOTE: margin = (container.height - child.height) / 2
    var margin = ($(this).parent().height() - $(this).height()) / 2;
    // default the margin to zero if it's a negative number
    // round the margin down to the nearest whole number
    // specify that the margin-top is in pixels
    return Math.floor(Math.max(0, margin)) + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black
}
div.inner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue
}
.horizontal-centre {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner horizontal-centre vertical-centre"></div>
```

**NOTE**: I made the example above smaller so you could see it properly.

Unfortunately though, there is now another problem, when I resize the browser the `margin-top` of the `div.inner` element stays the same.

I would like for it to be responsive and update it's `margin-top` property to the appropriate value when the window has been resized otherwise `div.inner` will go out of view and the page will look a like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Create a function of your code

```
function init_center() {..
```

Try calling the `init_center` function from the resize event of window

**SNIPPET**

```js
function init_center() {
  // set the margin top for ".vertical-centre" elements
  $(".vertical-centre").each(function() {
    // set the margin-top for the child
    $(this).css("margin-top", function() {
      // NOTE: margin = (container.height - child.height) / 2
      var margin = ($(this).parent().height() - $(this).height()) / 2;
      // default the margin to zero if it's a negative number
      // round the margin down to the nearest whole number
      // specify that the margin-top is in pixels
      return Math.floor(Math.max(0, margin)) + "px";
    });
  });
}

$( window ).resize(init_center); // Handle resize of window

init_center(); // Doing it first time
```

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black
}

div.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue
}

.horizontal-centre {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner horizontal-centre vertical-centre"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you code in a function

```
function align() {
  $(".vertical-centre").each(function() {
    // set the margin-top for the child
    $(this).css("margin-top", function() {
      // NOTE: margin = (container.height - child.height) / 2
      var margin = ($(this).parent().height() - $(this).height()) / 2;
      // default the margin to zero if it's a negative number
      // round the margin down to the nearest whole number
      // specify that the margin-top is in pixels
      return Math.floor(Math.max(0, margin)) + "px";
    });
  });
}
```

And run it on window resize as well

```
align(); // first run
$(window).on('resize', align); // when window resize
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.